# How to debug an interactive Node.js app in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you run and debug an interactive Node.js app (one that prompts the user to enter STDIN on the console) in VS Code using a simple launch (F5). I have so far been running the app using `node --inspect-brk .` and then attaching VS Code. This works fine, but I'm just wondering if there's a faster way. If I look at the DEBUG CONSOLE pane, I can see the STDOUT, but I can't add input there.

Comment: do you use a `launch.conf` file?

Comment: You'll find your answer here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes

Comment: Thanks, Randy. The file is `launch.json` to be accurate. I was using one, but was unaware of the `console` parameter.

Comment: sorry - that was off the top of my head. should have confirmed. Thanks the correction.Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Randy's comment was my answer with a link [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes). Thanks, Randy.

The solution is to configure the `console` value in your `launch.json` file. I added `"console": "integratedTerminal"` and now when I hit `F5` I can jump to the integrated terminal (`CTRL+<backtick>`) and interact with my app.